# Difference between destroy(), destroyRecursive(true), destroyDescendants()

Tags: dojo

While creating a widget i checking for existence of a div like below then destroying the content & again creating.

```
if (dijit.byId("TPContainer")) {
    dijit.byId("TPContainer").destroyRecursive(true);
    dojo.place('<div id="TPContainer"></div>',dojo.byId("TitleContainer"));
}
```

But before loading a HTML template

```
var container = dijit.byId("mainContainer");
container.destroyDescendants();
container.set("href", TemplateLink);
```

I just took the code from elsewhere. But not clear about the concept.
I don't know when to use which destroy function available with Dojo. can somebody explain when to use which destroy function? & what differentiate them?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Taking a look at the [Dojo api](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/) (currently 1.10) these methods are defined in `_WidgetBase` (though destroy comes from `dijit/Destroyable`) and inherited by all widgets. Since these are kind of buried in the api docs and not written in the _Widgetbase tutorial page I will list them here.

Internally, destroy*Blah* methods call `destroy` for themselves (where applicable) and their children so these function as simply helper methods to make it easier to destroy things.

---

### destroy(preserveDom)

**Parameter:** preserveDom

**Type:** Boolean

**Description:** If true, this method will leave the original DOM structure alone. Note: This will not yet work with _TemplatedMixin widgets

**Summary:**

> Destroy this widget, but not its descendants. Descendants means
>   widgets inside of this.containerNode. Will also destroy any resources
>   (including widgets) registered via this.own().
>
> This method will also destroy internal widgets such as those created
>   from a template, assuming those widgets exist inside of this.domNode
>   but outside of this.containerNode.
>
> For 2.0 it's planned that this method will also destroy descendant
>   widgets, so apps should not depend on the current ability to destroy a
>   widget without destroying its descendants. Generally they should use
>   destroyRecursive() for widgets with children.

---

### destroyDescendants(preserveDom)

**Parameter:** preserveDom

**Type:** Boolean

**Description:** (*Optional*) If true, the preserveDom attribute is passed to all descendant widget's .destroy() method. Not for use with _Templated widgets.

**Summary:**

> Recursively destroy the children of this widget and their descendants.

---

### destroyRecursive(preserveDom)

**Parameter:** preserveDom

**Type:** Boolean

**Description:** (*Optional*) If true, this method will leave the original DOM structure alone of descendant Widgets. Note: This will NOT work with dijit._TemplatedMixin widgets.

> Destroy this widget and its descendants
>
> This is the generic "destructor" function that all widget users should
>   call to cleanly discard with a widget. Once a widget is destroyed, it
>   is removed from the manager object.

---

In your first example, `destroyRecursive` will call destroy on the widget (but not the dom element because of the `true` parameter) that it is being called on. Contrast that to your second example where destroy is being called on only descendents of the widget that it's being called on. Since there is no `preserveDom` specified, it will destroy the dom elements as well as the widget registries.