# Dojo widget hiding / placing

Tags: dojo

I've created a number of my own widgets.  I've got a dom node where I'd like to display one of these widgets at a time, based on user choices.  So, I create one of the widgets, place it at the dom node and call startup:

```
this.widget1 = new MyWidget();
this.widget1.placeAt(this.theDomNode, "only");
this.widget1.startup();
```

This all works fine.  widget1 and theDomNode are properties of the object doing all this, hence the 'this' references.

Later on I wish to display a different widget there based on user action, so I repeat the exact same process with widget2:

```
this.widget2 = new MyOtherWidget();
this.widget2.placeAt(this.theDomNode, "only");
this.widget2.startup();
```

This works fine too.

The problem occurs when I want to return to a previously display widget.  In this case, I don't create a new instance of that widget, as it's already instanciated and referenced (e.g. by this.widget1 etc).  So, I do:

```
this.widget1.placeAt(this.theDomNode, "only");
this.widget1.startup();
```

However, this just clears the content of theDomNode and doesn't display widget1's content.  Likewise when showing any of the other widgets if it's not directly following instanciation.  It seems that when a widget is replaced in the domNode by another widget, it loses it's dom and can't be re-used.

Does anyone know how would be the best way to solve this?  One option I thought of is having a domNode for each widget and then changing the display property of the domNode itself to none to hide a widget and then back to show it.  However, before putting in this extra level I thought I'd throw the question out there in case there is a more simple way to do it.

Thanks
Simon

Comment: I am guessing that the `"only"` option used in the `placeat()` is creating the issue. Can you check your code **removing** the "only" argument. Alternatively you could try to clear out(nullify) the `theDomNode` variable before placing the next widget e.g `this.theDomNode.innerHTML = "";`

Comment: When you are placing the new widget you are destroying the DOM of the old widget, but the widget still exists.  it might be better if you destroy the widget then recreate it when you need it again.. or use show/hide instead

Comment: Thanks both, I think it is as you say @tik27 I am destroying the widgets DOM so there is nothing to reshow.  I've gone with purposefully calling the widgets destroy() method when it's being replaced and then creating it new when needed again.  This was just easier to move to than changing to a show/hide methodology although if the widgets state needed to be preserved then that would have been the way to go.

Comment: You probably want destroyRecursive() - see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24408703/difference-between-destroy-destroyrecursivetrue-destroydescendants